# File location if target path not specified with scp command

Tags: scp

To copy a folder from local computer to server I use

```
scp -r local_folder user@server:path
```

Now I forgot to specify the target path the first time:

```
scp -r local_folder user@server
```

Does anyone now if the folder has been copied and if yes, where in the server is it located at?

I issued the correct command later and copied the folder to my user directory but I just want to know whether the folder is also copied somewhere on the server the first time and find and delete it. I am a user and don't have permission to search the whole server. Thanks.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

When you use `user@server` without a ':' character, scp interprets `user@server` as the file name on the local machine to which you would like to copy your file.  So, you should find a file (or in this case a directory) called `user@server` in the directory from which you issued the `scp -r local_folder user@server` command.