# What is the target path of scp /localdir/ root@ubuntu:?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, scp

Note: My question is very similar to 
[File location if target path not specified with scp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494761/file-location-if-target-path-not-specified-with-scp-command/25496316)

But that question is asking what the target of this is:

```
scp -r /localdir/ root@ubuntu
```

My question is asking what the target of this is:

```
scp -r /localdir/ root@ubuntu:
```

Also if anyone's curious I found this syntax on the following webpage: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#copy-required-files-to-the-correct-locations

It's a Bash Script:

```
USER=ubuntu # customizable
CONTROL_PLANE_IPS="10.0.0.7 10.0.0.8"
for host in ${CONTROL_PLANE_IPS}; do
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.key "${USER}"@$host:
done
```

Comment: `scp` without a remote path is simply `cp /localdir/ .` (which will probably draw an error for a missing filename) Run as `scp -v /localdir/ root@ubuntu` to confirm.

Comment: I'm doubtful that the kubernetes official documentation would be wrong though. I'm trying to test it out with debian pods, but I'm getting scp port 22 refused after I installed openssh-server. Going to try making 2 linux VMs in a sec to see what such a command would do.

Comment: Unless you include a `-r`, the `/localdir/` will be omitted entirely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my example, I'll fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my test, I ran the command as follows to copy `test` folder from host `heron01` to host `heron02`:

```
yitian@heron01:~$ scp -r test/ yitian@heron02:
```

And the result shows that the `test` folder can be found at:

```
yitian@heron02:~$ pwd
/home/yitian
```

So, the result of your question is: The target directory is the `home directory` of the target user you are using in the scp command. In my example, the target directory is: `/home/yitian` in host `heron02`.

Comment: I found the same when I provisoned 2 linux boxes to test. 
I did scp ca.crt root@lanip:
then ran ls on the remote box and found ca.crt in my home directory, thanks you beat me to it :)